# How can we use Microsoft Groove with peers existing in both secure and unsecured network segments?

Tags: networking, security, windows

We have been instructed to implement a Microsoft Groove workspace.  This would normally not be a concern, but the workspace will be utilized by machines which exist in our internal/restricted network as well as from peers from an outside/unknown network.

Does there exist a best-practice for such an implementation?... or would this potentially expose the restricted network too broadly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groove seems designed around the idea that some clients may be behind firewalls and it has the ability to route around it's usual data channel TCP 2492 and use web ports (TCP 80 or 443).  If your secure network allows these ports outbound (and even if it doesn't) the clients will probably be able to get a session going.  If not, MS has a Groove Relay server product that can probably help facilitate communication if you're internal network is more restrictive.

The most useful documentation is probably here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261778.aspx

That being said, if you're allowing groove access between clients in a highly secure network and a low security network you are opening that secured network up to more risk.  I don't know your business, so I can only guess at some of new risks:

- Increased chance of malicious software being
  transfered in from a low security
  Groove Client to a high security client
- Increasedhance of sensitive
  data being accidentally or
  intentionally transferred to the low
  security zone
- Accidentally exposing vulnerable ports when opening firewall access